# Conflito jQuery-Prototype assíncrono

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

Pois bem eu detenho do uso das duas bibliotecas e então para que não houvesse conflito optei por usar o `jQuery.noConflict()` entretanto ao mesmo tempo tentei manter o uso do *dollar* mas meu código quebra devido a "assincroniedade" do código.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js'></script>
<script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>

<script type='text/javascript' src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.2.0/prototype.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
(function($){
    $("body").css('background-color', 'red');

    var x = 1;
})(jQuery);

console.log(x);
</script>
```

veja que X não é imprimido, há como resolver?

Comment: O que tem de assíncrono aí? Acho que nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não imprime porque o `x` está fora do escopo (deve estar dando um erro, não?).

Você precisa declarar `x` no escopo mais externo:

```
var x = 0; // DECLARE AQUI
(function($){
    $("body").css('background-color', 'red');
    // AQUI TIRE O var
    x = 1;
})(jQuery);

// Funciona!
console.log(x);
```

Comment: Como assim? Não entendi.

Comment: Existe alguma forma de se fazer isso só que com o prototype?

Comment: Dê um exemplo concreto do que você está tentando fazer, senão fica difícil dizer qualquer coisa.